# Why are my Homebrew bash completion paths suddenly missing?

Tags: bash, homebrew, bash-completion

Since my latest update of Homebrew, I'm suddenly getting the warnings below when attempting to set up path completion as I have always done, with commands (in my `bash_profile`) such as

```
source $(brew --repository)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
```

The only thing I've done since this last worked is run `brew update && echo; brew upgrade --all`.

How do I fix this error and restore access to my path completions. Why caused this to happen.

---

```
-bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/eb_completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/cabal: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc: No such file or directory
```

---

UPDATE: After the latest `brew update && echo; brew upgrade --all` I now get

```
-bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/eb_completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/cabal: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Change any entries that source Bash completions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39620103/656912) that say `$(brew --repository)` to `(brew --prefix)`.