# Homebrew fatal: needed a single revision (MacOs Sierra)

Tags: git, macos, terminal, homebrew, iterm

Not sure if this problem is related to upgrading to MacOs Sierra, but since that moment this error occurs when I run 'brew update'

```
→ brew update
Checking out v1.0.0 in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask...
To checkout master in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask && git checkout master
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'v1.0.0' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'refs/tags/1.0.0' which can not be resolved as commit?
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream refs/tags/1.0.0
Checking out v1.0.0 in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart...
To checkout master in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart && git checkout master
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'v1.0.0' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'refs/tags/1.0.0' which can not be resolved as commit?
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream refs/tags/1.0.0
Checking out v1.0.0 in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core...
To checkout master in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core && git checkout master
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'v1.0.0' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'refs/tags/1.0.0' which can not be resolved as commit?
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream refs/tags/1.0.0
```

I tried running

```
cd $(brew --prefix) && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
```

But it gives me this error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: I get this too, and I haven't upgraded to Sierra. I have however upgraded to Brew 1.0

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Sierra.

In addition to `brew --prefix`, which displays Homebrew’s install path,  there’s also `brew --repository`, which displays where it’s `.git` directory is located.

`man brew` says that claims that “for standard installs, the prefix and repository are the same directory”. Either the man page is out of date or my install isn’t “standard”, but my `prefix` is `/usr/local` and my `repository` is `/usr/local/Homebrew`.

Using the same command but with `cd $(brew --repository)` worked for me:

```
cd $(brew --repository) && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Full fix: `cd $(brew --prefix)/Homebrew && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: AKA `brew --repository`

Comment: Edited to add the full command and information about `brew --repository`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @thomasd, this has fixed the problem for me!

Comment: Homebrew recently (this week) migrated from `/usr/local` to `/usr/local/Homebrew`, and the docs may still be out of date.

Comment: [This will also mess up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39573787/656912) scripts that source bash completions with `(brew --prefix)`.

Comment: You should consider updating your answer to @YuriTkachenko comment.

Comment: Looks like it's a [know issue that will now fix itself.](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1091#issuecomment-249089640) Just need to brew update again. Thanks to @raxacoricofallapatorius for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. What worked was uninstalling `homebrew` and reinstalling it:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew analytics off
```

Answer (score 1):

This command fixed the error for me:

```
git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really worked for me, I had to resort to uninstalling and reinstalling Brew:

```
# change to home directory to avoid other errors later
cd ~

# uninstall brew
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && cd ~ && brew cleanup

 # reinstall brew
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

And the reinstall.