# Why am I told to 'cd' when updating Homebrew?

Tags: git, homebrew

Since my latest update of Homebrew (to 1.0.0), instead of just seeing

```
Checking out v1.0.1 in /usr/local/Homebrew...
```

when I `brew update` or `brew upgrade --all` I now see

```
Checking out v1.0.1 in /usr/local/Homebrew...
To checkout v1.0.1 in /usr/local/Homebrew run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew && git checkout v1.0.1
```

Is that an error I should do something about? What's going on here? Are updates no failing for me?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Found the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619889/homebrew-fatal-needed-a-single-revision-macos-sierra), which is very similar to yours:

```
cd $(brew --prefix)/Homebrew && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
```

It seemed to be caused by a difference in "prefix" and "repository" directories for homebrew.

Comment: Will I need to do that just once (to fix a bug or some incoherent stat on my end?) or each time I update?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I'm not sure yet, I suppose we'll find out next time a change is pushed to homebrew, which should be pretty soon.

Comment: [Now I get "no git repository".](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39642691/656912)

Comment: taking a closer look at the original answer, there is a comment by @yuri-tkachenko that seems to have the correct "full" fix for this problem. I've updated my answer to reflect that fix.

Comment: Aren't `(brew --prefix)/Homebrew` and `brew --repository` the same? If not, is there something I need to undo, having run the original answer?

Comment: And I [still get](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39642691/656912) `HOMEBREW_VERSION: >1.0.0 (no git repository)` when I `brew --config`. Is that just a bug that we need to wait to have fixed?

Comment: I get `-bash: git: command not found`, all thanks to the "I strongly recommend" in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957862/how-to-upgrade-git-to-latest-version-on-mac-os-x