# Errors when trying to install jenkins using Homebrew

Tags: jenkins, homebrew, devops

[screenshot of actual error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3kZa.png)

I have tried all the alternative ways to install jenkins on my macbook air but with no lack. I will appreciate anyone with the current solution to this.

This is the error message I get after running `brew install jenkins`:

```
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "jenkins".
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.
```

I also get a "fata" message

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
```

I am very knew to Jenkins and trying to learn usage.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYeHC.png)

brew doctor

then

Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
brew tap homebrew/core

then

brew install jenkins-lts

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in terminal:

```
rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
```

Then try:

```
 brew install jenkins
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this page : https://www.jenkins.io/download/lts/macos/

You must use `brew install jenkins-lts` to install jenkins.

Comment: I tried that already and these are the errors:
```
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "jenkins-lts".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Ok look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619889/homebrew-fatal-needed-a-single-revision-macos-sierra)


This command should fix the fatal error : `cd $(brew --repository) && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master` 

Retry after to install jenkins