# Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, node-modules, node-canvas

I'm on Mac OS and I have a problem with the `canvas` module. When I want to do an action with `canvas`, I have this error:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
> Referenced from:
> /Users/user/Desktop/Personnel/Dev/Bot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libcairo.2.dylib
> (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)   Expected in:
> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib Abort trap: 6

Then I've made some research and found that I have to install something with this command: `brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg`

But when I do this, I have this warning:

> Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "ca-certificates".
> ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found.
> ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)... Error: No previously deleted formula found.
> ==> Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps. Updating Homebrew... fatal: Needed a single revision Warning: No
> available formula or cask with the name "pkg-config".
> ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found.
> ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)... Error: No previously deleted formula found.
> ==> Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps.

I have tried to find a solution but I have decided to ask for help on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your homebrew is unable to update. Try uninstalling it with:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

Next, reinstall it with:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Comment: I've do it but, it don't really work, i still have the same error message with homebrew,. Did i have another way than homebrew to install what i need ?

Comment: You may want to look at a few of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619889/homebrew-fatal-needed-a-single-revision-macos-sierra.

Comment: it doesn't work, even if i uninstall and reinstall homebrew, i have the same problem..
As a result.. I think the best way is to find an alternative than homebrew to install the files i need.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i had the same problem a few days ago, after try many commands what worked for me was to unistall node js from the mac and install it again
I followed this steps:
https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-node-mac

then install nodejs 16 version
and problem gone!

Answer (score 0):

I stuck to this problem and tried to solve it in lots of ways but failed. My local machine was good before but after installing the latest node version this problem appears in the terminal and not accepting any type of js file in the machine [Reason is my mac version and the node version were not compatible].

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
```

Then installed a few previous versions of the [node from here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) and the problem disappears after installing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a **Mac OS** on my **VirtualBox**, where I got stuck with this error just now..

The problem was solved by simply **over-installing node (version 16)**, for example i took [this one](https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.20.0/) (-3 file, with `.pkg`)