# What is the meaning of : "Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin"?

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the message below when I run my server:

```
Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
```

I want to connect Postgresql with Django but it seems it doesn't work with this problem mentioned before.

This is the response of the shell when I am trying to run my server:

```
 raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/Nicolas/Desktop/OC/Python/Projets/P8_purbeurre/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/Nicolas/Desktop/OC/Python/Projets/P8_purbeurre/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.1.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/Nicolas/Desktop/OC/Python/Projets/P8_purbeurre/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
```

I have a macbook Pro High Sierra version 10.13.6.

Comment: Does this shed any light on your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69815052/symbol-not-found-chkstk-darwin

Comment: Got the same thing on python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361604/python-importerror-psycopg-chkstk-darwin-symbol-not-found-on-mac-10-13-6 How did you solve this?